# Can html5 poster size be varied for use as small thumbnail?

Tags: jquery, html, video

I want to use the html5 video poster attribute to set up a thumbnail for a video on a Joomla page. I'm using this markup:

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" poster="/templates/beez_20/images/ws_wst2.png" controls> 
<source src="/templates/beez_20/video/ws_wst2.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
      </video>
```

This works OK but the poster image displayed at the same size as the video which defeats the purpose of having a thumbnail. The SO page, "How to set the thumbnail image on HTML5 video?", is on the topic, but doesn't address the thumbnail size issue. I don't know whether this is achievable using the poster attribute or not. I'm happy to use js or jquery if necessary. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Poster is always going to try and display an image scaled to match the video element. If you want to display something a different size then you'll need to control the overlay (show/hide the element via CSS)

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Thanks, I've been try to control the display of the video thru jquery code but not succeeding. Could you indicate how to do this with CSS

Comment: not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do ... can you give a better example of what you're trying to achieve ...

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, I'm trying to use the poster image (a frame from the video) as a thumbnail for the video, such that when the thumbnail is clicked the video is displayed. I had understood "thumbnail" to imply a smaller picture (like those in Youtube), this is what I'm aiming for. I don't know whether this can be done.

Comment: so, you want something smaller than the video that you click on which then loads the bigger video element itself?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I think I understand as your requirement, this will display an image that can be set to one size, and then when clicked will show and start the larger video element playing. When the video is paused, or ended, it will revert back to showing the image (just to show the logic flow). When paused and resumed the video will continue from the same spot.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="videoContainer">
<div id="thumb"><img src="https://obm.one/images/lizard_goldeye.jpg" onclick="vidPlay()"></div>
<div id="vidContainer" style="display:none"><video id="video" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" mute controls>
</div>

<script>
thumb = document.getElementById("thumb")
vidContainer = document.getElementById("vidContainer")
video = document.getElementById("video")
video.addEventListener("pause",vidPause)
video.addEventListener("end",vidPause)
function vidPlay() {
    thumb.style.display = "none"
    vidContainer.style.display = "inline"
    video.play()
}

function vidPause() {
    console.log("bobby")
    thumb.style.display = "inline"
    vidContainer.style.display = "none"    
}
</script>

<body>
```